# iOS Next/Previous Button that iterates through tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, tableview

I have a tableview that is populated by a plist and when a cell is clicked, a textview in the detailViewController is populated with a string from the value associated in the plist.

All this works perfectly however now I want to add previous and next buttons in the `detailViewController` that will iterate through the tableview.

Here is my `prepareForSegue` on my `TableViewController`:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"promisePush"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        NSInteger section = [indexPath section];
        NSString *key = [uniqueArray objectAtIndex:section];

        NSArray *nameSection = [sections objectForKey:key];
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [nameSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        DetailViewController *dvController = [segue destinationViewController];

        //dvController.array = titles;

        dvController.selectedRow = indexPath.row;
        dvController.titleCat = [dictionary valueForKey:@"Title"];
        dvController.kjvText = [dictionary valueForKey:@"kjvText"];
        dvController.nkjvText = [dictionary valueForKey:@"nkjvText"];
        dvController.nivText = [dictionary valueForKey:@"nivText"];
        dvController.verse = [dictionary valueForKey:@"verse"];

        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Promises" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

       self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
    }
}
```

Right now the kjvText is passed to the textView called txtdText in the detailViewController

```
[txtdText setText:nkjvText];
```

I'm able to get the indexPath.row passed to the detailViewController through the

`dvController.selectedRow = indexPath.row;`

and can iterate the int to the next number through

```
- (IBAction)nextPromise:(UIButton *)sender {
    selectedRow = selectedRow + 1;
}
```

but I don't know how to communicate that number to the next indexPath.row in the tableView which will update the textView in the detailViewController.

I have a feeling I need to set the TableViewController as the delegate for my DetailViewController but I'm not exactly sure what that would look like. Any direction is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, can't you simply call the following method on your UITableView?

```
[UITableView selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:]
```

This selects a row in the receiver identified by index path, optionally scrolling the row to a location in the receiver.  See the docs on UITableView.

Comment: The method would need to be called from the DetailViewController back to the TableViewController and then the updated text from the next row would need to be communicated back to the DetailViewController to update the textView. It seems like a delegate would need to be implemented.

Comment: I assumed you had an IBOutlet in your DetailViewController storing a reference to your UITableViewController.  With regard to communicating data back to the DetailViewController, I assumed there was already a mechanism in place to do this when a cell is tapped.  The method above is equivalent to tapping a cell, so those existing mechanisms should just work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about an IBOutlet from my DetailViewController to my UITableViewController. Those are two separate ViewControllers and an IBOutlet just connects things to its own ViewController. I have a segue from the UITableViewController to my DetailViewController.

Comment: Can you create a property on the destination viewcontroller (detailviewcontroler) and then in the segue, saved a reference to the source viewcontroller?  This will give you access to any publicly exposed properties methods on the source viewcontroller.  Given that you do need to be mindful of endpoints in the tableview, you may want to expose a method in your tableviewcontroller that the detailviewcontroller calls to select the next row.  Also, given that this is a master/detail scenario, both viewcontrollers should always be in memory so a strong reference from detail to master should be ok.